# Get First result from DataTable.Select without For Each loop

Tags: vb.net

The below For loop does not loop at all. Is there any optimized way to do the same without For loop:

```
For Each drID As DataRow In dttable.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID")
    NewID = CInt(drID.Item("ID"))
    Exit For
Next
```

I have tried changing this with

```
NewID = IIf(dt.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID").Length > 0, dt.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID")(0).Item("ID"), 0)
```

Is there any other optimized way to change this For loop which does not even loop at all.

Comment: Hi, as it stands, this is likely to be closed. Consider revising your question to make it more focussed and understandable. Currently, it is hard to tell what is being asked. Try changing the title as well.

Comment: @AlastairPitts I think question is clear enough - he wants do the same (take `"ID"` from first result of `.Select()` method call without `For Each` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want get `"ID"` from first row in your DataTable without using `For Each` loop. You can do that using LINQ `FirstOrDefault` method - it returns first element of collection or default value (`Nothing` for all reference types) it collection hasn't got results:

```
Dim firstRow As DataRow = dttable.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID").FirstOrDefault()

If Not firstRow Is Nothing Then
    NewID = CInt(firstRow.Item("ID"))
Else
    NewID = 0
End If
```

You need `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your file to make it works.

Or without LINQ:

```
Dim results As DataRow() = dttable.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID")

If results.Length > 0  Then
    NewID = CInt(results(0).Item("ID"))
Else
    NewID = 0
End If
```

Comment: Can be done without using Linq. Since the Framework used is 2.0 ?

Comment: Sure - just save whole `DataRow()` array from `Select` method into a variable.