# 'Item' is not a member of 'DataRow()'

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to use this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756995/get-first-result-from-datatable-select-without-for-each-loop) but I keep getting this error

`'Item' is not a member of 'DataRow()'`

Does anyone know why? Or how I can get the first row of a data table?

```
Dim results As DataRow() = Students.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID")

Test1Highest.Text = results.Item("Name") & " Got the highest in test 1!"
```

Comment: But you're not using that code. You omitted the `FirstOrDefault` call and expected everything else to work the same way. Why would it?

Answer (score 2):

From [DataTable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-6.0), we can see that the `results` variable will be an Array of `DataRow` objects.

Therefore, to access the first item in the list, you will need to add an `Array Indexer`.

Change this line:

> Test1Highest.Text = results.Item("Name") & " Got the highest in test 1!

to be

```
If results IsNot Nothing AndAlso results.Count > 0 Then
    Test1Highest.Text = results(0).Item("Name") & " Got the highest in test 1!
Else
    Test1Highest.Text = "No results!"
End If
```

Or, you can do (using `FirstOrDefault()`)

```
Dim singleResult As DataRow = Students.Select("ID=1 and FirstName='Karthik'", "ID").FirstOrDefault()

If singleResult IsNot Nothing Then
    Test1Highest.Text = singleResult.Item("Name") & " Got the highest in test 1!
Else
    Test1Highest.Text = "No results!"
End If
```

---

Looking at the question you linked to, the accepted answer has the command `FirstOrDefault()` being called from the result of the `Select` statement. This, like the name suggests, will return the first item in the array or a Null value if there are no elements in the array.